# Samsung Galaxy S4 eye tracking

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-s-4

In the Samsung Galaxy S4 connection eye tracking video it shows a person watching a video. While watching the video if they turn their head the video will pause.

I want to ask, if the video is seen by two or more people what will happen to the video?

Comment: If you are not Mr. Robinson Crusoe and still waiting for Friday (oh, it's Friday today): why not pick another person and try? Shouldn't be too hard. You then could let us, who don't have a S4, know the results - as simply "picking a S4" would be more complicated :)

Comment: @Izzy I think the "eye in video" bit means he's seen a video with it in and wants to know what will happen so not sure if he owns one.

Comment: @Peanut Oh -- right, I didn't consider that possibility. Sorry for that, kumar!

Answer (score 1):

In S4, Eye movements are tracked by Front Camera. In this principle, the Persons Eye focused within the front cam is taken into consideration. (This doesnt works when there is no light or  dim light). This works well based on the viewing angle  (around 45Degree or something) of persons eye and Device front camera. This makes the possibility of detecting, one persons eye. so the play/pause depends on the single user not the multiple people. This makes sense when there is lot of crowd behind the user who is watching the video.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: Irrespective of number of people watching the device, only one person who falls under the specific angle is tracked. When that person, moves away his head, the phone is paused. So, it wont track multiple users eye movements. (Another Reason is, The light source (usually infrared) is directed toward the eye. which moves in straight direction and Its not scattered to detect eye. And The camera tracks the reflection of the light source along with visible ocular features such as the pupil.)